# A modular arithmetic notation having same attributes with an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

How can you prove that $f$, a function given piecewise depending on the value of its input modulo some number, has the same attributes as $g$, a function given directly by an equation?

For example, define $f(x) = x^2$ if $x \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, and $f(x) = x + 1$ if $x \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$.

Then I transform the modular arithmetic notation into $$g(x) = (x^{1 + x \ \mathrm{mod}\ 2} )+(1 - (x \ \mathrm{mod}\  2))$$

I don't know if it is possible and if it possible what kind of proving technique should I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that particular example, first show that $g(x) = f(x)$ for every $x \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, and then show that $g(x) = f(x)$ for every $x \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$. That covers all possible inputs to $g$ and $f$.

For example: if $x$ is even, then $$g(x) = x^{1+0} + (1-0) = x+1 = f(x)$$

If $x$ is odd, then $$g(x) = x^{1+1} + (1-1) = x^2 = f(x)$$

---

In order to take your $f$ and produce a corresponding $g$, the simplest thing that occurred to me was to define $$g(x) = (x \ \mathrm{mod} \ 2) x^2 + (1-(x \ \mathrm{mod} \ 2)) (x+1)$$

This also works. The clearest way to define a function is usually piecewise, though: in your question, the definition of $f$ is much, much more readable (and probably more useful in almost all circumstances) than the definition of $g$.